# I am trying to create a vehicle registration portal. For some reason the get() is only receiving the owner name

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I am trying to create a vehicle registration portal. For some reason, the get() is only receiving the owner's name.

I'm trying to practice inheritance and used the concept of inheriting properties from the parent class "vehicle".
This one is the child class "get info"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class vehicle{
    private:
        int noPlate;
        char owner;
        int registrationNo;

    public:
        int modelNo;

        void setnoPlate_setRegNo_setOwner( char number, int rNumber, char ownerName){
            noPlate = number;
            registrationNo = rNumber;
            owner = ownerName;
        }

        void displayInfo(){
            cout<<"***Vehicle Information Portal***";
            cout<<"              -----------           \n";
            cout<<"Owner Name: "<<owner<<"\n";
            cout<<"Registered Number Plate: "<<noPlate<<"\n";
            cout<<"Registration Numaber: "<<registrationNo<<"\n";
        
        }
};
```

> INHERITING VEHICLE CLASS

```
class getInfo : public vehicle{
    public:
        void get(){
            char tempNoPlate;
            int tempRegNumber;
            char tempOwnerName;
            cout<<"\n***Vehicle Registration Portal*** \n";
            cout<<"              -----------           \n";

            cout<<"Enter your Registratered Owner name for your vehice:"<<"\n";
            cin>>tempRegNumber;
        
            cout<<"Enter your number plate of your vehice:"<<"\n";
            cin>>tempNoPlate;

            cout<<"Enter your Registration Number of your vehice:"<<"\n";
            cin>>tempRegNumber;

            setnoPlate_setRegNo_setOwner(tempNoPlate, tempRegNumber, tempOwnerName);

        }

        void display(){
            displayInfo();
        }

    
};
```

> MAIN FUNCTION

```
int main(){

    getInfo vehicleInfo;
    vehicleInfo.get();
    vehicleInfo.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not tag questions with both the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags unless you're really fond of downvotes — it annoys people unless the question is about the interworking of C and C++, which you question does not seem to be.   The code is clearly C++ code and not C, so I've removed the C tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In **void get()** you are trying to get owner name in Registration number that is of int type, therefore it breaks
- Secondly you **Owner Name** should be of string type other than Char since char can only store 1 character.
- In class vehicle, noPlate is of int type, you must also take int type tempNoPlate in derived class **get info**

Here is the correct code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class vehicle{
    private:
        int noPlate;
        string owner;//Change in owner data type
        int registrationNo;

    public:
        int modelNo;

        void setnoPlate_setRegNo_setOwner( int number, int rNumber, string ownerName){ //Change in ownername data type
            noPlate = number;
            registrationNo = rNumber;
            owner = ownerName;
        }

        void displayInfo(){
            cout<<"***Vehicle Information Portal***";
            cout<<"              -----------           \n";
            cout<<"Owner Name: "<<owner<<"\n";
            cout<<"Registered Number Plate: "<<noPlate<<"\n";
            cout<<"Registration Numaber: "<<registrationNo<<"\n";

        }
};
class getInfo : public vehicle{
    public:

        void get(){
            int tempNoPlate; //this should be of int type instead of char
            int tempRegNumber;
            string tempOwnerName; // change
            cout<<"\n***Vehicle Registration Portal*** \n";
            cout<<"              -----------           \n";

            cout<<"Enter your Registratered Owner name for your vehice:"<<"\n";
            getline(cin, tempOwnerName); // change,  GETLINE here is used to read space in name, you can use cin >> tempOwnerName but
                                        // it wouldnt read space character.

            cout<<"Enter your number plate of your vehice:"<<"\n";
            cin>>tempNoPlate;

            cout<<"Enter your Registration Number of your vehice:"<<"\n";
            cin>>tempRegNumber;

            setnoPlate_setRegNo_setOwner(tempNoPlate, tempRegNumber, tempOwnerName);

        }

        void display(){
            displayInfo();
        }


};

int main(){

    getInfo vehicleInfo;
    vehicleInfo.get();
    vehicleInfo.display();
    return 0;
}
```